# Ajax Success Fails to Initiate

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a simple ajax post to the server..

```
$(".invite-team-members-submit-btn").click(function() {
  $.post("invite_team_member", { token: $("#token").val(), email: $("#email").val(), team: $("#team").val() })
    .done(function (responseText) {
      responseText = jQuery.parseJSON(responseText);
      alert(responseText.response);
    })
    .fail(function (data) { alert("ERROR: " + data); })
    .then(function () { alert("Something should happen."); });
});
```

The JSON returned looks like this...

```
{"response":"Person has been invited."}
```

My response header in the console looks like this...

```
Response Headers
  Cache-Control max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
  Connection    close
  Content-Type  application/json; charset=utf-8
  Date  Wed, 22 May 2013 21:45:07 GMT
  Etag  "e5b5e12acbcc78372b2a861027b66c05"
  Status    200 OK
  Transfer-Encoding chunked
  X-Request-Id  d835ce021eff7733d67ebfcdd468bdf2
  X-Runtime 0.007909
  x-ua-compatible   IE=Edge
```

In my console I see that it the server and returned the appropriate text, but I don't receive an alert in my browser. I'm just out of idea's on what's wrong. Has jQuery updated something that I'm missing?

Comment: try turn on the firebug on firefox. check if there is a valid response.

Comment: Did so and posted the details in my answer.

Comment: could you post the ajax code that we suggested?

Comment: I'm using Explosion Pills code, which is both in my code and my answer. I feel like it's satisfactory for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) incorrectly.  You mean to use `$.ajax` and specify the `type: "post"` property.

`$.post`'s first argument is the URL.  In your case it's an object.  I think that perhaps jQuery ends up using the current page URL to make a request instead (which is why you see one), but I can't be sure.  You could rewrite this as:

```
$.post("invite_team_member", {data: data})
    .done(function (responseText) { alert(responseText); })
    .fail(function (data) { alert("ERROR: " + data); });
```

Comment: I updated my code to match your answer but I'm still not getting an alert. Maybe it's a back-end issue after all.

Comment: @jason328 if you're not getting the `.fail` alert either then that means the request is not even running I think.  What if you add a `.then` afterwards with an alert?

Comment: Still the same thing, no alert. If nothing is running how am I getting a response from console log telling me I sent the right request to the server? I double checked and my server is running properly.

Comment: @jason328 do you get a syntax error of any kind in JavaScript?  Can you set up an example on jsfiddle.net?  Are you returning JSON or setting `Content-type: application/json` header from the server?

Comment: No, no syntax error. I'll try to post something to jsfiddle. I'm returning just text. I can try json though. Just thought it would be a lot easier to render text versus json.

Comment: @jason328 not a *lot* easier, but I was just thinking there may be a JSON parse error if you were trying to return JSON

Comment: Hmm.. just tried it out with JSON and still no luck. Posted an update on my question. Will try to build an example off of JSFiddle, just not sure how to replicate the server response.

Comment: @jason328 I think that at this point your question has changed too substantially from the original question.  I would keep the original question as it was, accept this answer (so I get some rep :P), and I'll continue helping you in another question

Comment: I agree on that. Writing up a new question now.

Answer (score 1):

use `$.ajax()` then set the type to `"POST"`

Comment: Did so and still have the same result, no alert.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
mydata = "name=Jon&location=USA";   
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url :  'myphp.php',
    data : mydata               
}).done(function(msg){
    alert("DONE");
});
```